# How do I generate a new id which is not in an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<int>` which contains all existing ids. I would like to generate a new id, which is any `int` that is not in existing ids. I have a hacked together a solution, but I would like to the know the best way to do this.

```
// Inefficient solution
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    int i = Int32.MinValue;
    while (existingIds.Contains(i)) // There is a case where all ids are taken!
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

---

Update: here *best* is defined as:

- Meeting the requirements
- Predictable performance
- Smallest big-oh possible
- Should work for any `IEnumerable` implementation, albiet faster for some than others
- Should be stateless

Comment: "The best" way is the one that works and fits your functional and non-functional requirements.

Comment: Stuff existingIds.Max() in a private static int _nextID and increment it when you need one

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use only positive values? There's nothing wrong with a negative id, but I don't know, it seams a little odd to me.

Comment: @Magnetron -2 is negative but not odd (not even a little) :P

Comment: _The_ most efficient solution is either keeping track of the last issued ID and just incrementing that, so you don't have to iterate all existing IDs to find the maximum each time; or make sure `existingIds` is sorted when you retrieve it, so you can replace the `.Max` by `.Last`(`OrDefault`).

Comment: It depends on how often you are going to get missing integers in the range and how often items are deleted.  The most efficient method would be to put deleted items into a list so when you need to add a new item you grab from the deleted list.   To create a the deleted list you may need to run code to find missing integers which can be done by sorting existing integers and finding missing numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care to use the *lowest free* ID you can simply take the successor of the currently biggest ID:

```
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    return existingIds.Max() + 1;
}
```

Of course there will be a problem if `Int32.MaxValue` *and* `Int32.MinValue` are already contained, so you'll need some special treatment for this case.

But seeing how many ID's there are in an `Int32` range, this should rarely happen so it would be ok to implement a more expensive algorithm for that corner case.

---

If you're afraid of an overflow, you can improve your first approach by sorting the sequence at first and then scanning for a gap (instead of testing for each possible `int`-value):

```
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    int i = Int32.MinValue;
    foreach(int id in existingIds.OrderBy(id => id))
    {
        if (id != i) return i;
        if (i == Int32.MaxValue)
            throw new Exception("We ran out of IDs!");
        i += 1;
    }

    return i; // this now one more than the last/biggest existing ID
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Ivan to beat me to my big mistake, improved the second approach accordingly

Comment: You may use the `TakeWhile` overload that accepts a delegate with 2 arguments: the value and the index. That way you may avoid introducing a free `int i` variable.

Comment: @zerkms right, but OP starts at `Int32.MinValue` so I would have to substract something again or adjust the comparison....don't know what's better/more efficient/more readable.

Comment: @zerkms And I need the final index outside the lambda....(note that the inner returns are there to stop or continue the `TakeWhile`).

Comment: @RenéVogt The id does not have to start at `Int32.MinValue`. The function only guarantees that it is fresh (and ideally throw an exception once all ids are taken).

Comment: @sdgfsdh well, my second suggestion meets these requirements.

Comment: to handle overflow it's as easy as adding `if(existingIds.Max() == Int.MaxValue){throw handledexception;}` also needs to check for when the collection is empty or null.

Comment: @BartCalixto No, I'm looking for _gaps_ in the list, So although `Int32.MaxValue` maybe already contained, I still could use `42` (if it's free). I know that it maybe bad to re-use free IDs, but that's what OP's original approach did, too. So I assumed it valid.

Comment: It's funny how the people overuse LINQ. In the second approach, everything except `OrderBy` is using the side effects - sequence producing method `TakeWhile` to mutate closure variable. And of course, since it's not consumed (remember deferred execution), the method always returns `int.MinValue`. While simple `foreach` on ordered enumerable will not introduce closure, will be much more readable and more importantly, will simply work.

Comment: @IvanStoev omg I'm embarassed, you're right...while writing it I forgot to execute it.....

Comment: @IvanStoev updated the answer.

Comment: Cool:) I personally would use a "two liner" body like `if (id != i) break;
i = checked(i + 1);`, but that's just a matter of taste. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is this line of code executed in a loop :

```
existingIds.Contains(i)
```

This has complexity of O(N2). One way to improve it is to use collection that works with hashes rather than indexes. For example `HashSet<T>` :

```
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    var hashedIds = new HashSet<int>(existingIds);

    int i = Int32.MinValue;

    while (hashedIds.Contains(i)) ++i;    // now it use fast O(1) lookups

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Actually this answer is much better than any based on ordering.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, Ivan

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add some exception handling. This will not get missing numbers in ranges.

```
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    if (existingIds == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingIds));
    }
    if (!existingIds.Any()){
        return int.MinValue;
    }
    var lastId = existingIds.Max();
    if (lastId == Int.MaxValue){
        throw new ApplicationException("Sorry there are no more int available. Consider switching to int64.");
    }
    return lastId+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you'll never have so many items that your Id equals Int32.MaxValue, than the following would fast enough

```
public static int GetFreshId(this IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
{
    return existingIds.Max() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any gaps on your list of IDs

```
public static int GetFreshId(IEnumerable<int> existingIds) {    
    if (existingIds.Any()) {
        int i = existingIds.Max();  
        if (i == Int32.MaxValue) {
                throw new Exception("Ups...");
        }

        return i++;
    }

    return 1; // or what else
}
```

if you have probably I think your solution OK, maybe just add checking to avoid overflow